# How to buffer a burst of events into fewer resulting actions

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to reduce multiple events into a single delayed action. After some trigger occurs I expect some more similar triggers to come, but I prefer not to repeat the resulting delayed action.  The action waits, to give a chance of completion to the burst.
**The question: How can I do it in an elegant reusable way?**
Till now I used a property to flag the event and trigger a delayed action like below:

```
public  void SomeMethod()
    {
        SomeFlag = true; //this will intentionally return to the caller before completing the resulting buffered actions.
    }
    private bool someFlag;
    public bool SomeFlag
    {
        get { return someFlag; }
        set
        {
            if (someFlag != value)
            {
                someFlag = value;
                if (value)
                    SomeDelayedMethod(5000);
            }
        }
    }

    public async void SomeDelayedMethod(int delay)
    {
        //some bufferred work.
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        SomeFlag = false;
    }
```

below is a shorter way, but still not generic or reusable... I want something concise that packages the actions and the flag, and keeps the functionality (returning to the caller before execution is complete (like today)).  **I also need to be able to pass an object reference to this action)**

```
 public void SerializeAccountsToConfig()
    {
        if (!alreadyFlagged)
        {
            alreadyFlagged = true;
            SerializeDelayed(5000, Serialize);
        }
    }
    public async void SerializeDelayed(int delay, Action whatToDo)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        whatToDo();
    }

    private bool alreadyFlagged;
    private void Serialize()
    {
        //some buferred work.
        //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Accounts, Formatting.Indented);
        //Settings1.Default.Accounts = json;
        //Settings1.Default.Save();
        alreadyFlagged = false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you wanting this to be threadsafe? Because right now it is not.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd in it's current form, I bet this question would be closed as "pseudocode" on codereview. Please see the [codereview help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["Be careful when recommending Code Review"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/1803692)

Comment: Consider it as a question for a code that doesn't work... My "generic" answer would be for the trigger flag to call `DelayedAsync(Action stuffToDo, out flagToClose, int int delay = 5000);` but the compiler says I cannot use out or ref in Async.

Comment: it's not pseudo. the second example is an actual working code, the first one is to make the flow clear. 
I don't know enough about threading, but I can confirm multiple threads can set the trigger flag to true...so my answer should be "I want it to be thread safe, and I want to know why it is not ? I think only one thread at a time will eventually call the time consuming action, and I don't care which thread it will be.

Comment: Maybe you should use Reactive Extensions.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov If I added the Reactive Extensions Main nugget, what would the code that accomplishes the same purpose look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the solution proposed by Andrew, here is a more generic solution.
Declaration and instance creation of the delayed action:

```
public DelayedSingleAction<Account> SendMailD;
```

Create the instance inside a function or in the constructor (this can be a collection of such actions each working on a different object):

```
SendMailD = new DelayedSingleAction<Account>(SendMail, AccountRef, 5000);
```

repeatedly call this action

```
SendMailD.PerformAction();
```

Send mail is the action you will "burst control". Its signature matches :

```
public int SendMail(Account A)
    {}
```

Here is the updated class

```
    public class DelayedSingleAction<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, int> actionOnObj;
    private T tInstance;
    private readonly long millisecondsDelay;
    private long _syncValue = 1;

    public DelayedSingleAction(Func<T, int> ActionOnObj, T TInstance, long MillisecondsDelay)
    {
        actionOnObj = ActionOnObj;
        tInstance = TInstance;
        millisecondsDelay = MillisecondsDelay;
    }

    private Task _waitingTask = null;

    private void DoActionAndClearTask(Task _)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:h:mm:ss.fff} DelayedSingleAction Resetting SyncObject: Thread {1} for {2}", DateTime.Now, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, tInstance));
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _syncValue, 1);
        actionOnObj(tInstance);
    }

    public void PerformAction()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _syncValue, 0) == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:h:mm:ss.fff} DelayedSingleAction Starting the timer: Thread {1} for {2}", DateTime.Now, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, tInstance));
            _waitingTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecondsDelay)).ContinueWith(DoActionAndClearTask);
        }
    }

    public Task Complete()
    {
        return _waitingTask ?? Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a thread-safe and reusable solution.

You can create an instance of `DelayedSingleAction`, and in the constructor you pass the action that you want to have performed. I believe this is thread safe, though there is a tiny risk that it will restart the timer just before commencing the action, but I think that risk would exist no matter what the solution is.

```
public class DelayedSingleAction
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly long _millisecondsDelay;
    private long _syncValue = 1;
    public DelayedSingleAction(Action action, long millisecondsDelay)
    {
        _action = action;
        _millisecondsDelay = millisecondsDelay;
    }

    private Task _waitingTask = null;
    private void DoActionAndClearTask(Task _)
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _syncValue, 1);
        _action();
    }

    public void PerformAction()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _syncValue, 0) == 1)
        {
            _waitingTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_millisecondsDelay))
                               .ContinueWith(DoActionAndClearTask);
        }
    }

    public Task Complete()
    {
        return _waitingTask ?? Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

See this dotnetfiddle for an example which invokes one action continuously from multiple threads.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/el14wZ

Comment: I tested and it works and it fits my need (does what I do with my "bad code"). I wish it wasn't as complex :).   I'll check this thread over time, other proposals, and in the mean time, start migrating all my bad code to this.

Comment: I just tried using it and found that I cannot use it to call a method that takes parameters. Is there a way to make it more generic so that it's not restricted to Action type?

Comment: @Guy - possibly, but you'd have to work out what happens to the parameters. Does it just use the parameter of the first call? The last call? Aggregate them somehow?

Comment: I was imprecise. It's not a parameter, it's a reference to an instance. so I consider this will not be an issue (but the idea is that when executed, the method sees the latest data). Below is what I did.  In the calling class  `public delegate int ActionA(Account a);` in DelayedSingle:   `private readonly Account act;
public readonly BallE.ActionA _actionA;
public DelayedSingleAction(BallE.ActionA actionA,Account Act, long millisecondsDelay)
        {
            act = Act;
            _actionA = actionA;
            _millisecondsDelay = millisecondsDelay;
        }`  **Works but not generic**

Comment: I just added a working generic solution (that fits my above need). TThe only thing that's weird about it is that my FUNC returns int, and it cannot cannot be used (you cannot expect a return when calling multiple times where there's just one execution).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're interested in RX here simple console app sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // event source
    var burstEvents = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));

    var subscription = burstEvents

        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)) // collect events 3 seconds
        //.Buffer(50) // or collect 50 events

        .Subscribe(events =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(events.First()); // take only first event

            // or process event collection
            foreach (var e in events)
                Console.Write(e + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        });

    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think Andrew's proposal might better suite me, but I'll see.